# Error: Folder does not contain an export named 'Navbar1'

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I keep getting errors that I'm pretty sure shouldn't be there.

This is the error I keep getting:
./src/App.js
21:24-31 './components/Navbar/Navbar' does not contain an export named 'Navbar1'.

However here is my code for Navbar:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Navbar.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Container, Navbar, NavbarBrand, Nav, Button, Accordion } from 'react-bootstrap'



class Navbar1 extends Component {
    
    
    render() {
        return(
            <Navbar bg='light' variant='light'>
            <Container >
              <NavbarBrand className='brandcolor'>
              <h1>ETHER<span>SHARE<i className="fab fa-ethereum"></i></span></h1>
              </NavbarBrand>
            </Container>
            
            <Container >
              <Nav >
                <ul>
                  <Nav.Link className='linkitem'>
                    <li>
                      <Accordion>
                      <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
                        <Accordion.Header className='linkitem'>Account</Accordion.Header>
                        <Accordion.Body className='linkitem'>Settings</Accordion.Body>
                        <Accordion.Body className='linkitem'>Taxes</Accordion.Body>
                      </Accordion.Item>
                      </Accordion>
                    </li>
                  </Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link className='linkitem'><li>Stats</li></Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link className='linkitem'><li>Pool</li></Nav.Link>
                </ul>
              </Nav>
            </Container>
            <Container > 
                <Button variant="light">Connect Wallet</Button>
            </Container>
          </Navbar>
        )
    }
} 

export default Navbar1;
```

This is my code in App.js, My app was working just fine an hour ago idk what the problem is:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Navbar1 } from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import { Footer } from './components/Footer/Footer';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { faCheckSquare, faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';



library.add(fab, faCheckSquare, faCoffee)

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
        <Navbar1 />
       
        <Footer />
      
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you add the image of your file structure?

Answer (score 1):

For default export

Do this

```
import Navbar1 from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
```

Not this

```
import {Navbar1} from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
```

Comment: Check if all the files are saved,  even then you are gettinh an issue, try this Change Navbar1 to NavbarOne ,

Comment: I did both, still didnt work... Do you think there could be something wrong with the framework? idk

Comment: Do this last thing change you filename to something else, change the component's folder name to Header and file to index.jsx.

Comment: Is it normal that my App.js did not have render() {}

Comment: I added render and that didnt work either tho

Comment: Your app is a functional component, you don't need render method, try changing the Navbar1 to functional component instead

Comment: I did that too didn't work... keeps saying "Check the render method of `NavbarOne`."

Comment: I appreciate you sticking thru to help me too thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `export default`, you should import it as (without curly braces):

```
import Navbar1 from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
```

In order to import it as you did in App.js, you should export it as a named export:

```
export { Navbar1 }
```

Comment: I did without curly braces too.... so delete the word 'default' at the bottom of the Navbar component? Thats not working either.